# pass pointers into function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am very new to javascript, and I would like to do something very simple, but I can't manage to.
Here is my code globally:

```
var Test = class Test 
{
    constructor(var_x, var_y) {
    this.x = var_x;
    this.y = var_y;
```

}
};

and

```
var y = {Value: 2};
var test1 = new Test(0, y.Value);
y.Value +=2;
console.log(test1);
```

my problem is that I display (0,2), and as I incremented y.Value, I expected (0,4). 
What did I miss ? Thank you!

Comment: In JS primitives are always passed by value. Pass an object or array if you want to maintain a reference.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I'm a beginner and I don't understand your comment :(

Comment: Primitives such as words and numbers are only passed by value (a copy is created). Objects and arrays are passed by reference (a pointer). If you change a property of an object, all reference to the object will reflect the change, because they point to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour can be explained because you are passing a **value** to the constructor, **not** a reference:

```js
var Test = class Test 
{
    constructor(var_x, var_y) {
        this.x = var_x;
        this.y = var_y;
    } 
};

var y = {Value: 2};
var test1 = new Test(0, y.Value);
console.log(test1)
test1.y +=2;  // <-- NOTE
console.log(test1);
```

You could also do something like this (which I'd **not** recommend due to a bad software pattern):

```js
var y = {Value: 2};

var Test = class Test 
{
    constructor(var_x) {
        this.x = var_x;
        this.y = y;   // <-- NOTE
    } 
};


var test1 = new Test(0, y.Value);
console.log(test1)
y.Value +=2;
console.log(test1);
```

In this example the `Test.y` value is a reference to another variable (`var y`)

Comment: Thank you! What I am trying to do it to modify test1.y value by modifying y value, I want to declare test1 and not modify it after.

Comment: @Letchi yes this is why i added the second example (where `test1` is **not** modified directly afterwards)

Comment: Ok thx. It's possible to call a one argument constructor with two arguments ?

Comment: @Letchi I guess this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript